# Undefined method `tagged' for Formatter error after Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, activeresource

I have upgraded from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4 by following the Ruby Screencast guide. My tests are running and the server starts, yet I receive an error when I send a request:

```
ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `tagged' for #<Formatter:0x000000057f5dc8>

/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/quiet_assets-1.0.2/lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/mahoni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have I have looked at the code, and it does not make sense for me. It calls `logger.tagged`. The object behind the variable `logger` is not a logger, but a `Formatter` object. This is strange.

Any idea what could cause this? So far I:

- deleted my `Gemfile.lock`
- `gem update rails`
- `bundle install`
- `bundle update`

In this and different orders. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using a customer logger?

Check in `config/environments/development.rb`. That's where the logger is usually assigned.

Also, look in `config/initializers` for logging-related monkey patches.

I was using Chris Powell's logger patch, and it caused a very similar error.

If you're using that patch, there's an updated one for Rails 4:
http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/beautiful-logging-for-ruby-on-rails-4/

Comment: Great answer. We had a similar problem with a custom logger in config/initializers.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same error, got rid of it by re-initializing the logger.

Added a new file on config/initializers, called it log_formatting.rb

with this code:

```
Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new "log/mylog.log"
Rails.logger.formatter = proc{|severity,datetime,progname,msg|
    "[#{datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}] [#{severity}]: #{msg}\n"
}
```