# custom logger in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

It looks like Rails4's logger, unlike Rails3's, finally supports a custom formatter, like the ruby stdlib logger again.

```
Rails.logger.formatter  # => #<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007ff81757d890 @datetime_format=nil>
Rails.logger.formatter = SomeFormatterClass
```

However, when I try to give it a formatter class that would be sufficient for stdlib Logger formatter:

```
[2014-03-12 16:23:27] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `tagged' for #<FormattedRailsLoggerFormatter:0x007fd816545ad8>
/Users/jrochkind/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
/Users/jrochkind/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
```

Does anyone know, is a custom formatter actually a supported feature of Rails4? And is how you are meant to do it documented anywhere?

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176447/undefined-method-tagged-for-formatter-error-after-rails-4-upgrade ?

Comment: I had not found that StackOverflow you mention prior to you pointing it out, but I do not find that it answers my question either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question, I've figured it out.

Rails4 provides a config variable, `config.log_formatter`.  You would probably set it in your `config/application.rb`, along with other application config.

You should set it to an object implementing the stdlib Logger Formatter interface: Basically, you have to provide a method `call(severity, time, progname, msg)` that returns the formatted log line.

Note you set it to an object, NOT the class name, eg:

```
config.log_formatter = MyFormatter.new
```

You should *not* try to set Rails.logger.formatter directly -- Rails expects you to set it via config, and does some tricky stuff to make your formatter and logger work properly with Rails when you use the config.  You can see that, as well as see that indeed `config.log_formatter` is used, in [Rails source code here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b1867c85fa934caad1cd7410e1bd9bc0463a2f42/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb#L42).  (Thanks to github and it's awesome code search and display ui, is how I tracked this down and figured out the existence of `config.log_formatter`)

In Rails4, you should **not** need to monkey-patch any parts of Rails just to use a custom log formatter, just use `config.log_formatter` instead. (In Rails3 you did need to monkey-patch one or another to get custom log formatting).

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on why setting `config.log_formatter` wouldn't work for me? See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974180/enabling-a-custom-formatter-in-rails).

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone else, in Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.0, this is what worked for me:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    require 'my_log_formatter'
    ...
    # Custom log formatter that uses JSON
    config.log_formatter = MyLogFormatter.new
  end
end
```

To make this happen:

```
# lib/my_log_formatter.rb
class MyLogFormatter < ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, timestamp, progname, message)
    if message.present? && message.exclude?('Started GET "/assets')
      {
          app: Rails.application.class.parent_name,
          process_id: Process.pid,
          level: severity,
          time: timestamp,
          progname: progname,
          message: message
      }.to_json + "\r\n"
    else
      ''
    end
  end
end
```

Some notes:

- The `if` statement prevents log entries with no message, and log messages that log the serving of asset files.
- The `+ "\r\n"` adds a CR+LF to the end of the line, so it remains somewhat human-readable in the rails server console.
- I added `app` because I am sharing a single log file among many apps.  You could delete this in a system that uses just one Rails app.
- I find `process_id` comes in handy when you are reviewing logs on a busy server.