# Enabling a custom formatter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've written a custom formatter for Rails:

```
module Logging
  class GeneralFormatter < Logger::Formatter
    def call(severity, time, program_name, message)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And according to the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22382634/1103543), all I have to do to use it is set

`config.log_formatter = Logging::GeneralFormatter.new`

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work—my custom formatting isn't kicking in. And yet, if I instead define this as well:

```
module Logging
  class GeneralLogger < ActiveSupport::Logger
    def initialize(*args)
      super(*args)
      @formatter = GeneralFormatter.new
    end
  end
end
```

Then I can do `config.logger = Logging::GeneralLogger.new` and my logs are formatted as desired.

What am I doing wrong with setting `log_formatter`? I'd rather not define my own Logger when all I want is custom formatting.

---

**EDIT** (responding to comments, and adding more detail from a little more digging):

I'm setting `config.log_formatter` in `application.rb` and it testing in development, and it appears to be working *to an extent*, in that calling `Rails.logger.formatter` gives me my custom class. But here's the behavior I'm seeing on calling `Rails.logger.warn("test")`:

1. `test` is printed out to the console (followed by a newline).
2. *Then* the `call` method of my formatter is entered.
3. The return value of the `call` method is never printed out to the console.

Where what I thought would happen (and what I want to happen is):

1. The `call` method of my formatter is entered.
2. The return value of the `call` method is printed out to the console.
3. Nothing else is printed.

Am I misunderstanding how formatters work?

---

**EDIT Again** (providing clearer example):

When I have this defined:

```
def call(severity, time, program_name, message)
  puts "Checkpoint 1"
  "Checkpoint 2"
end
```

and call `Rails.logger.warn("Checkpoint 0")`, I expect to see:

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpiont 2
```

but instead I see:

```
Checkpoint 0
Checkpoint 1
```

Comment: Is it failing to work on test or prod?

Comment: where do you set config.log_formatter? Open a rails console and run Rails.logger.log_formatter and see what that shows

Comment: Added more detail to my original question; thanks for the questions.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, let's try again.

I don't actually have an answer -- instead, I am unable to reproduce your problem. I will give you the steps I took and what I saw, perhaps you will be able to compare to what you've done to see how it's different.

- You didn't say what version of Rails you have, I started with the latest 4.1.1. Built a brand new application `rails new logtest`.

Added a file at `./lib/custom_formatter.rb` that looks like this:

```
class CustomFormatter < Logger::Formatter
  def call(severity, time, program_name, message)
    # I think it makes no sense to have a raw `puts`
    # in a log formatter, but I'll leave it in to
    # copy you. Almost certainly a bad idea though. 
    # commented out. 
    puts "Checkpoint 1"
    return "Checkpoint 2"
  end
end
```

Added this to my existing `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'custom_formatter'
config.log_formatter = CustomFormatter.new
```

Now I start up the application with `rails server`, and access `http://localhost:3000/test`. I expect to get an error message, because I haven't defined any routes or controllers or anything. But because of my weird custom logger, I expect all the log lines to be essentially replaced by "Checkpoint 1" and "Checkpoint 2". Indeed that's what's happened. My console looks like this:

```
  [2014-06-03 18:22:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
  [2014-06-03 18:22:49] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
  [2014-06-03 18:22:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=57113 port=3000
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 1
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 1
```

My development.log looks like this:

```
  Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2Checkpoint 2
```

So clearly that custom 'formatter' isn't doing anything useful -- and I strongly recommend against putting a straight 'puts' line in a real formatter.

But my custom formatter is indeed being used, all log lines are 'formatted' as the fixed string 'Checkpoint 2' (with no newline at the end!), and the additional "Checkpoint 1" is also puts to stdout.

So your problem is not reproducible by the steps you've given, if I try to do what you say you've done, I dont' have your problem. So, this is indeed how debugging works, it is frustrating!  I suggest you follow my steps to create a test app above and see if it works for you too. Then you've got to compare your actual app to that little test app and figure out how it's different, to manifest the problem in your actual app. One common way to do this is make a copy of your actual app, and begin stripping out everything you can, to get the barest possible app that still manifests the problem. Odds are, in doing this, you'll figure out yourself the cause of the problem -- but if you don't, you can make your bare bones demonstration app available to others trying to help you, and they can maybe figure out what in it is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this, upvoted for effort. First, I wasn't actually using a useless logger in my project with a `puts` statement in it—that was simply to provide a simple, reproducible example for the purposes of my question. My mistake was in not understanding that the Rails console doesn't use the formatter you set (see my answer for a link to the PR I wrote to change this), so in fact my example *was* reproducible, I just didn't highlight the fact (because I didn't realize it) that it's specific to working in the console. (My `development.log` was always fine.)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I was conflating formatting to the logs with formatting to the Rails console output. I've created a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15470) and [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15476) to make the console behave the same way as the logs do.

Comment: Thanks for adding this clarification. For others, please be sure to check your `log/development.rb` file to ensure the logging is formatted the way you intend, instead of looking at the console output.

Answer (score 0):

If you say the call method of your formatter is entered, then clearly your custom formatter is being called, right?

You haven't actually provided us the source of your formatter implementation, but it seems most likely that formatters don't work how you think, if it's being called but not doing what you want. I'm not actually an expert in how formatters work, but maybe find some examples existing known to work formatter implemetnations, maybe in rails source, and see how they differ from yours?

You say that the return value from your formatter#call is printed to the console -- does that mean it's working after all? What else do you expect?

(The formatter has no control over WHERE the log is sent, in development in Rails I think it's sent both to the console and a development log file. That can be changed, but not with a custom formatter)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but actually as I said the return value from my formatter#call is **not** printed to the console—that's the whole problem. See my updated question for an example.

Comment: Sorry for the misdirection. Your question above actually says "The return value of the call method is printed out to the console."  I think you were missing a 'not'? That's what confused me I guess. Sorry, I don't know, I guess it's time to debug Rails, which can be enlightening.

Comment: When I said that in my original question, it was listed as what I *expected* to happen, not what *did* happen.